# Find the maximum value of a function $f(x) = |x(x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 4)(x - 5)(x - 6)(x - 7)|$ where $3 \leq x \leq 4$

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

Find the maximum value of a function $f(x) = |x(x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3)(x - 4)(x - 5)(x - 6)(x - 7)|$ where $3 \leq x \leq 4$.

This question is supposed to be solved without using derivatives.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: I'd probably look at $t=x-3.5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is symmetric around the center point $x=\frac{7}{2}$. Letting $x = y + \frac{7}{2}$, we have:

$$ f(x) = \left| \left(y + \frac{7}{2}\right) \left(y + \frac{5}{2}\right) \left(y + \frac{3}{2}\right) \left(y + \frac{1}{2}\right) \left(y - \frac{1}{2}\right) \left(y - \frac{3}{2}\right) \left(y - \frac{5}{2}\right) \left(y - \frac{7}{2}\right) \right| $$

$$ f(x) = \left| \left(y^2-\frac{7^2}{4}\right) \left(y^2-\frac{5^2}{4}\right) \left(y^2-\frac{3^2}{4}\right) \left(y^2-\frac{1^2}{4}\right) \right| $$

Since $3 \leq x \leq 4$, $-\frac{1}{2} \leq y \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $y^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}$, so all four factors are non-positive.

$$ f(x) = \left(\frac{7^2}{4} - y^2\right) \left(\frac{5^2}{4} - y^2\right) \left(\frac{3^2}{4} - y^2\right) \left(\frac{1^2}{4} - y^2\right) $$

$f(x)$ clearly decreases when $y^2$ increases, so the maximum of $f$ is achieved when $y^2$ is as small as possible. The smallest possible is $y^2=0$, at $x=\frac{7}{2}$.

$$ \max_{3 \leq x \leq 4} f(x) = \frac{7^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 3^2}{2^8} = \frac{11025}{256} \approx 43.066 $$

Comment: I was going to say that ... using the symmetry is neat. It is in fact easy to show that there is just one turning point between each of the zeros [just noting as a fact] and the symmetry shows where this one must be.

Comment: @MarkBennet Is it "easy to show" with a non-calculus approach? We can certainly notice the derivative of the function inside $|\cdot|$ is a 7th degree polynomial with a zero somewhere in each of 7 distinct intervals.

Comment: Probably not without calculus thinking about it - fair comment.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum of the product occurs at the maximum of the *logarithm* of the product.  Write this out to see the maximum must occur at $x = 3.5$.

Specifically, maximize $\log x + \log (x-1) + \cdots + \log (x -7)$

Consider the sum of just the first and last terms.  How would you maximize that sum?  (Convince yourself that it would be for $x = 3.5$.)  Now consider the sum of the second and the second-to-last term.  Again, $x=3.5$.  And so on.

Put these answers together to see the result.

Answer (score 1):

If the use of AM-GM inequality is allowed, then
$$
f(x)=x(7-x) \cdot (x-1)(6-x) \cdot (x-2) (5-x) \cdot (x-3)(4-x) \\
\le \left(\frac 72\right)^2 \cdot \left(\frac 52\right)^2 \cdot \left(\frac 32\right)^2 \cdot \left(\frac 12\right)^2 = \frac{11025}{256}.
$$
And all four equality hold simultaneously at $x=3.5$.

Answer (score 0):

**Graphical Comment.** The function crosses the x-axis at $0, 1, 2, \dots, 7.$ So it seems that the maximum for $x$ in $(3,4)$ must be about halfway between $3$ and $4.$

```
curve(abs(x*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3)*(x-4)*(x-5)*(x-6)*(x-7)), 3, 4, ylab="y", main="")
```

[image]

A numerical search shows that the maximum $y= 43.0664$ is very nearly at $x = 3.5.$

```
x= seq(3,4,by=.001)
y = abs(x*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-3)*(x-4)*(x-5)*(x-6)*(x-7))
x[y==max(y)]
[1] 3.5
max(y)
[1] 43.06641
```

Computations in R.